# Bootstrap mixins not loading properly while access from remote

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap

I have my Django running on the server, map to 0.0.0.0:8000, when I access it from localhost bootstrap works fine, but when I access it from outside (i.e. remotely it doesn't work)

[image: localhost]
[image: external/remote]

Comment: include cdn of bootstrap may help you..

Comment: How you are referencing to css file? Posting template code will be helpful.

Comment: If your all static assets are giving 404 then consider checking your STATIC_URL.

Comment: it works on localhost, but not when access through external ip.